# How to delay resorting a rendered list until after saving an edited list item in Ember/Ember-Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say I have a Movie model that hasMany Sequences. When displaying the page to edit a movie, I display the sequences and allow the user to edit any of the sequences in-line on the page.

The page displays sorted sequences by using an array proxy in the MovieEditController:

```
sequences: function() {
  return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Em.SortableMixin, {
    sortProperties: ['start'],
    content: this.get('model.sequences')
  });
}.property('model.sequences')
```

The problem occurs when editing a sequence's start property. The list of sequences displayed on the page gets resorted as the property input field is being filled out. Instead, the list should only be resorted when the changed is saved and persisted.

What would be the most idiomatic Ember way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've created a ModelProxy mixin so I can have an intermediate proxy object to work with:

```
var defineProperty = Ember.defineProperty;

var ModelProxy = Ember.ObjectProxy.extend({
  model: Ember.computed.alias('content'),

  // override this ObjectProxy method to not propagate changes to the model
  setUnknownProperty: function(key, value) {
    defineProperty(this, key, null, value);
    return value;
  },

  // only propagate proxy attributes when the proxy is saved
  save: function() {
    var keys = Em.keys(this),
        content = this.get('content');

    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      content.set(key, self.get(key));
    }, this);

    return content.save();
  }
});

var ModelProxyMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  proxy: null,

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set('proxy', ModelProxy.create({ model: this }));
  },

});
```

This is mixed into the Sequence model:

```
var Sequence = DS.Model.extend(ModelProxyMixin, { /*..*/ });
```

The movies/edit template then uses the proxy when displaying the in-line form fields:

```
{{#each s in sequences itemController='sequence'}}
    {{#if isEditing}}
        {{#with s.proxy}}
        <tr>
            <td><button {{action 'save'}}>Save</td>
            <td>{{input value=start}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/with}}
```

The SequenceController calls #save on the proxy which will then update the original model:

```
actions: {
  save: function() {
    this.get('model.proxy').save().then(function() {
      this.toggleProperty('isEditing');
    });
  }
```